# Default SSH Option disable GCP

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I just created a VM but SSH option is disable i can't SSH.

Please Help how to enable SSH.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few issues that can cause this.

1. Is the instance running?
2. Did you try to ssh to the instance via [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell)? I can see that you only have an internal IP address, so you can use this command:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh internal-instance-name --internal-ip
```

3. Do you have one of the following roles assigned? *Owner*, *Editor*, *Compute Admin*, *Compute Instance Admin*?
4. Is port 22 enabled under your firewall?

Also GCP has a really good [ssh troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) that can help you.